# Python module variable not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I have just started learning python. I am using python 2.7.5
I created the test module named "t.py" as below:

```
$cat > t.py
import os
def greeting(name):
  print("Hello, " + name)
c=os.system('clear')
```

When I am trying to use the module in python c is not working but greeting is working

```
$python
>>> t.greeting("test")
Hello, test
>>> t.c
0
```

Can you please advise why t.c is not clearing the screen within the python.Thanks.

Comment: If you've just started learning Python, you should definitely use the most recent version - 3.7 - not the very-out-of-date 2.7.

Comment: Thanks Daniel Roseman , the server I am using has the version 2.7.5 installed. There might be future work on python 2.7.5 so I am getting acquainted with it. I will try to install the version 3.7 on my home computer though thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you've set `c` as a variable (the result of one call of `os.system('clear')`), not a function. You'd have to do

```
def c():
   os.system('clear')
```

and then call

```
>>> t.c()
```

---

FYI, `subprocess.call` is preferred over `os.system` which only exists for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Ohh...wow... thanks FHTMitchell for your help :) Plus 1 and will accept as the answer in 9 minutes due to the limit. :D

Comment: And thanks for subprocess tip too... >>> import subprocess
>>> import subprocess as sp
>>> sp.call('clear')
0